# image in while loops

Tags: php, mysql, image, file

I'm trying to create echo image in while loops with table, but I'm getting the error . please see part of the code

```
                $image = $rows['image']; 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM boxes ";
                $result = $db->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        if ($row['status'] == 1)
                            $visible = "visible";
                        else
                            $visible = "hidden";

                        if ($row['side'] == 1)
                            $side = "right";
                        else if ($row['side'] == 2)
                            $side = "left";
                        else $side = "not set yet";

                        echo "



        <tr>
          <td width=\"15%\" rowspan=\"3\"><img src="data:image' image \. ($row['image']).'" />';</td>
          <td width=\"85%\" colspan=\"5\">".$row['title_boxe'] . "</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=\"5\">desc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Visible</td>

          <td>sss</td>
          <td><form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['id_boxe'] . "'/>
              <input type='submit' name='update' value='Update' class=\"btn btn-primary\"/></form></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=\"6\">hr</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td colspan=\"6\">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>


                     ";
                    }
                }
                ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

what wrong with this line of code inside of php  that i can figure out how to solve this...

```
<td width=\"15%\" rowspan=\"3\"><img src="data:image' image \. ($row['image']).'" />';</td>
```

many thanks for your help.

Comment: show your error message

Comment: is not showing errors message,  is just showing red line on my html editor as errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you echo is wrong   ( and to me is not clear what you are doing with `<src='data:image  image ..` if you need  a \ but this interfer
with quote escape it using \

```
      echo "
    <tr>
      <td width='15%' rowspan='3'><img src='../image/box-manage/" . $row['image'] ."' />;</td>
      <td width='85%' colspan='5'>". $row['title_boxe'] . "</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='5'>desc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Visible</td>

      <td>sss</td>
      <td><form method='post'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['id_boxe'] . "'/>
          <input type='submit' name='update' value='Update' class='btn btn-primary'/></form></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='6'>hr</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan='6'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>";
```

Comment: I'm not sure why have put \\ , but the file path name is like ../images/box-manage, so is this mean that have to write in php <td width='15%' rowspan='3'><img src='data:image  ..images \ box-manage  \\ " . $row['image'] ."' />;</td>  is this is correct code!

Comment: yes, is works, this new to me, I learned something new. thanks for your help.